# Why its necessary to pass output variable every time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used to have procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[do_something]
    (
    @id int
    )
AS
...
...
```

I needed to have some return value, so I changed this to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[do_something]
    (
    @id int,
    @closed int OUTPUT
    )
AS
...
...
```

But now I need to pass `closed` variable every time when I want to execute this procedure.

```
EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[do_something] 
   @id
  ,@closed OUTPUT
GO
```

Is it possible to execute it without passing this variable (sometimes I dont need to analyse `closed`)?

In many languages you can either store return value like this:

```
bool result = DoSomethingAndGetResult();
```

or execute function without storing return value:

```
DoSomethingAndGetResult();
```

Comment: You can set default value to the OUTPUT parameter, or change the input parameter to IN/OUT and assign that one

Answer (score 2):

You have two other options to return data from a stored procedure:

1. Use a `Return` statement. This is handled similar to an output variable in client code, but does not require you to assign the parameter.
2. `SELECT` the output into a result set. This can require a client system capable of checking multiple result sets if you also select other data. ADO.Net, for example, let's you do this either via a DataAdapter/DataSet or DataReader/MoveNext(), but not every library or ORM built with ADO.Net exposes the feature.

Comment: It should be noted that the RETURN statement can only return an int. It is intended to return the status of the execution instead of results. Most people agree that an output parameter is a better option.

Comment: Actually an output parameter is the correct solution, just with a default value

Answer (score 1):

In additional to @JoelCoehoorn's answer, you can make the output parameter optional by assigning it a default value and then you aren't required to pass it every time.

SQL Server Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/specify-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16#-specify-parameter-default-values

```
create proc dbo.test (@p1 int = null, @p2 int = null output)
as
begin
    set @p2 = 1;
end
go
--this works
exec dbo.test;
```